# using back quotes in C++ to exec bash script

Tags: c++, bash

I want to execute a script from my C++ codes that needs an argument. this argument is the context of a txt file that I need to cat to provide the argument. how can I call this script in C++ with argument ?

here is my code : my_script.sh needs an argument, I want to get the value of this argument by catting my_file.txt. my question is could `cat /tmp/my_file.txt` be interpreted from C++ ??

```
const char * my_array[] = {

"/dir/my_script.sh `cat /tmp/my_file.txt` "   
  .
  .
  .   
 };
```

Comment: What is the library you're using to call the bash script?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c

Comment: @Scony depends if s/he is using the c `system` call.

Comment: I suspect he got no idea about `system`

Comment: @Scony I think the problem is in executing a string containing backquotes - not so trivial even with `system` ...

Comment: Well @user3877544 you should probably use `execv()`

Comment: system() can't return any values, so it's obvious that system() can't be used. But is there a way to retrieve bash values from C++ ? or specifically how to execute a bash script in C++ that return a value ?

Answer (score 2):

The backquotes, or any other construct and interpreted by the shell (`bash`) when *reading* a line, and it then executes the command **after converting the parameters**. When you execute a command you start it with its parameters, or can use `system`, or the `bash -c` construct to parse the parameters, but this convertion does not occurs.

I would strongly advice you to use a shell script that takes the name of the file as parameter, and that call any command that you want using backquotes or `$()` because the script is execute by the shell and the shell knows what to do with backquotes and `$()`.

You could have an intermediary script, say `/path/to/laucher` containing

```
#! /bin/bash

/dir/my_script.sh `cat $1`
```

and in your c++ code, you just call :

```
system("/path/to/launcher /tmp/my_file.txt");
```

Comment: `system()` won't be able to return the output of the executed command to the caller. I think what the OP rather needs is to kick that idea with the backticks, and use a pipe to execute the command they want.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of back-quotes in C++ strings or char arrays to call arbitrary code.

Are you sure you do not want the [system() function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) ?

Comment: `system()` won't be able to return the output of the executed command to the caller. I think what the OP rather needs is to kick that idea with the backticks, and use a pipe to execute the command they want.

Comment: No, but you can route the output and check the file(s). That is what I do regularly with perl, so why not do this with C++? *BUT* the command "foo 1>foo.out 2>foo.err" isn't exactly portable...